# What is the probability f(p) of A winning the match?

Tags: probability

[image: Question]

Here's my approach:

Let A denote the event "A wins the game" and B denote the event "B wins the game"

I am supposed to calculate the probability f(p)

There are two possible cases:-

i) A wins within 4 games

Possible cases: AAA,ABAA,BAAA,AABA

ii) A doesn't win within 4 games

Possible cases: AABB(A and B occur 2 times each) ABABABAB...(A and B occur k times each) AA

AABB can be arranged in 6 ways

ABABAB.... can be arranged in $(2!)^k$ ways (A and B are adjacent to one another)

Now :

f(p) = P(case i) + P(case ii)

P(case ii) = $(6 (p^2) (1-p)^2 ) \sum_{k=1}^∞  2^k . p^k . (1-p)^k. p^2  $=$(6 (p^4) (1-p)^2 ) \sum_{k=1}^∞  2^k . p^k . (1-p)^k$

= $(6. 2 . p^5 . (1-p)^3)/(1-2p+2p^2)$ (The denominator seems correct)

P(case i ) = $p^3 +3p^3(1-p)$

f(p) = $p^3 +3p^3(1-p) + \frac{(6. 2 . p^5 . (1-p)^3)}{(1-2p+2p^2)}$

The expected answer is not produced by solving the above equation.Where did I go wrong?

Edit:-
I finally figured out the mistake that I made in the above solution.

In P(case ii) = $(6 (p^4) (1-p)^2 ) \sum_{k=1}^∞  2^k . p^k . (1-p)^k $, I replaced $\sum_{k=1}^∞$ with $\sum_{k=0}^∞$ . There has to be one case when B does not occur after the tie, i.e. A occurs only two times.

P(case ii) =  $(6 (p^4) (1-p)^2 ) \sum_{k=0}^∞  2^k . p^k . (1-p)^k $
=  $(6 (p^4) (1-p)^2 ) .[1+2p(1-p)^1+2^2.p^2.(1-p)^2+...]$
=$(6 (p^4) (1-p)^2 ) .\frac{1}{1-2p(1-p)}$

f(p) = P(case i) + P(case ii)
=$p^3 +3p^3(1-p)+(6 (p^4) (1-p)^2 ) .\frac{1}{1-2p(1-p)}$
=$p^3[1+3(1-p)+\frac{6p(1-p)^2}{1-2p(1-p)}]$
=$p^3[1+(3-3p)+\frac{6p-12p^2+6p^3}{1-2p+2p^2)}]$
=$p^3[\frac{(1-2p+2p^2)+(3-6p+6p^2-3p+6p^2-6p^3)+(6p-12p^2+6p^3)}{1-2p+2p^2)}]$
=$p^3\frac{(4-5p+2p^2)}{1-2p+2p^2}$

Comment: It's hard to list all the possible scenarios.  We could have $AABBABAB\cdots$ for instance.  Or $BAABABA\cdots$ and so on.  Better to do it with states.  Just keep track of $A-B$ (that is to say, the difference between the number of games $A$ has won and the number of games $B$ has won), and whether or not $A$ needs to win by $2$. There are only finitely many possible states.

Comment: Please use MathJax to display your mathematics.  I, for one, simply find it too hard to follow your work if you don't do so.  Primer at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: **[I].** $\,(6 (p^4) (1-p)^2 )\;$ should be $\;(6 (p^2) (1-p)^2 )$ (the players have won *two* games each.)$\;$ **[II].** Infinite series is best avoided. $\;$ **[III]** You should check the Algebra after the correction for **[I].**

Comment: There's nothing remotely unclear about this question.  It proposes a solution, notes that it's not the expected solution, and asks for help locating the error.  The only issue I see is the failure to use MathJax.  I'm voting to reopen this question.

Comment: @RobertShore: I entirely agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ can win in three games with $3-0$ or $3-1$, else they must reach $2-2$ and then has to win by a difference of $2$

- To win directly, $A$ wins with $p^3 + \binom31 p^3(1-p) = 4p^3 -3p^4$
- To reach $2-2, Pr = \binom42p^2(1-p)^2$
- Let $P(A$ ultimately wins from $2-2$) be $d$
  Then either A wins in straight two points or is back to equal scores, thus eqivalent to $2-2$, so $d = p^2 + 2p(1-p)d$ which gives $d = \frac{p^2}{2p^2-2p+1}$
- Putting the pieces together, $$P(A\; wins) = p^3+3p^3(1-p) + [6p^2(1-p)^2] \times \frac{p^2}{2p^2-2p+1}$$

### Added

On giving it to Wolfram the answer I get is
$$P(A\; wins) = \frac{p^3(2p^2-5p+4)}{2p^2-2p+1}$$

which [tallies with the book answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify%5B+p%5E3%2B3p%5E3%281-p%29+%2B+6%28p%5E2%281-p%29%5E2%29*p%5E2%2F%282p%5E2-2p%2B1%29%5D+&key=fgf4n)

Comment: Your probability for a direct $A$ win isn't correct because you're double counting the "sweep" case by allowing the solo win attributed to $B$ to be Game $4$.  You also need to calculate the probability that you get to a $2$-$2$ tied state.

Comment: @Robert Shore: Yea, thanks, have corrected

Answer (score 1):

Let $q = 1 - p.$

---

Suppose that the match is tied 2-2 after 4 games.

Let $R$ denote the probability of A's winning the match, **in that event**.

Then

$$R = p^2 + 2pqR \implies R(1 - 2pq) = p^2 \implies R = \frac{p^2}{1 - 2pq}.$$

After $4$ games either A has won all $4$, A has won $3$ out of $4$ (where it is harmless to play the 4th game if A won the first three games), the match is split 2-2, or A has lost.

Therefore, A's probability of winning is

$$p^4 + 4p^3q + 6p^2q^2R = p^4 + 4p^3q + \left[6p^2q^2 \times \frac{p^2}{1 - 2pq}\right]$$

$$= p^3 \times \left\{ ~  p + 4q + \frac{6pq^2}{1 - 2pq}
~\right\}$$

$$= 
p^3 \times \left\{ ~\frac{[ ~(1 - 2pq)(p+4q) ~] + 6pq^2}{1 - 2pq}
 ~\right\}. \tag1 $$

Then:

- $1 - 2pq = 1 - 2p(1 - p) = 1 - 2p + 2p^2.$
- $p + 4q = p + 4(1 - p) = 4 - 3p.$
- $6pq^2 = 6p(1 - 2p + p^2) = 6p - 12p^2 + 6p^3.$

The given answer is

$$\frac{p^3(4 - 5p + 2p^2)}{1 - 2p + 2p^2}. \tag2 $$

Comparing (1) and (2), the problem reduces to showing that

$$[(1 - 2pq)(p + 4q)] + (6p - 12p^2 + 6p^3) = (4 - 5p + 2p^2). \tag3 $$

---

$$(1 - 2p + 2p^2)(4 - 3p) = 4 - 11p + 14p^2 - 6p^3.$$

Therefore, the equality in (3) above is established.

Answer (score 0):

I would treat the $2$-$2$ case separately.  Calculate the probability that $B$ has won by the end of Game $4$.  Then you know the probability of arriving at a $2$-$2$ tie.

$A$ wins within $4$ games with probability $p^3+3p^3(1-p)=4p^3-3p^4=p^3(4-3p)$.

$B$ wins within $4$ games with probability $(1-p)^3+3p(1-p)^3=(1-p)^3(1+3p).$

A $2$-$2$ tie occurs with probability $y=1-[p^3(4-3p)+(1-p)^3(1+3p)]$.

In a $2$-$2$ tie, the probability that $A$ wins immediately is $p^2$, the probability that $B$ wins immediately is $(1-p)^2$, and the probability that we reach another tie is $2p-2p^2$.  This, if you reach the tied state, the probability $x$ that $A$ eventually wins the game satisfies $x=p^2+(2p-2p^2)x$, so $x=\dfrac{p^2}{2p^2-2p+1}$.

Thus, the probability that $A$ wins is $p^3(4-3p)+xy$.

I haven't worked through the algebra to confirm this results in the expected answer, nor have I worked through your algebra to see whether the mistake is there or in the way you've set up the problem.

A tweak to this approach is to observe that if the match is tied $1$-$1$, the probability of an $A$ win is $x$, calculated above, because we're already in the position where the first player to lead by $2$ wins.

$A$ will lead $2$-$0$ with probability $p^2$ and once there, will win without going to "overtime" with probability $p(2-p)$.

$B$ will lead $2$-$0$ with probability $(1-p)^2$ and once there will win without going to "overtime" with probability $1-p^2$.

Comment: **1.** I do not understand your Pr for a $2-2$ tie. Why isn't ir $\binom42p^2(1-p)^2 \;$? **2.** Regarding your "tweak" from $1-1$, that is ruled out because the question specifically mentions that "if the players win two games each, the match is to continue..."

Comment: I suspect the two expressions for a $2$-$2$ tie are equal.  The point of the tweak is that the probability of victory from the $1$-$1$ position is the same as the probability of victory from the $2$-$2$ position.